# Access to this web site has been blocked because a short-term Transaction Lock has been taken

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In Sharepoint 2010 : After a year, create a new item and update item on the site is very slow
some times I encounter this error :Access to this web site has been blocked because a short-term Transaction Lock has been taken.
Please guide me
Tanks

Comment: How many items are in the list that you are trying to add to. Does each item have security permissions set? How busy are your SQL Servers in terms of Disk I/O?

Comment: List1 = 40000 Items - list2 = 20000 Items - list3 = 500000 Items  - Total Memory of db server = 64 G - SQL Servers in terms of Disk I/O  = 34 Read/39 Write - Does each item have security permissions set? = No -

Comment: So the lists are they using Lookup columns? Have you got any custom event receivers?

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the design of the solution. The issue looks like the way that the large lists are interacting with one another.

The following knowledge base article  is going to provide some useful information.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813(v=office.14).aspx

Areas to look at will be whether there are any suitable columns which can be setup as an indexed column. For example if you are doing lookups by date.

Have you got Synchronous Event Receivers running can they be moved to Asynchronous event receivers so the UI recovers more quickly.